# How can i limit a user in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Can any one please tell me how can i limit a user to edit only his post.I used the role editor plugin but it allow the user to edit all users post.I'm creating a classified site plugin  where a user can post(custom post type)and he can edit his post.

Comment: role editor plugin will work,

Comment: Can't you just set the user's role to Author in the user admin page?  According to the [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Summary_of_Roles) page of the Codex that should do what you want.

Comment: @Hobo i already tried it but no luck can you give me an example please

Comment: @JothiKannan Tried it but the user can edit everyone's post. I just want him to only edit his post.

Comment: you must set `Author` role for the users to publish post and manage their own posts

Comment: use this plugin for you create roll and manage user roll to access post, custom post and other. http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/

Comment: Tanks All I fixed the issue. I'm creating a plugin so how can i use a plugin in it we can solve the issue using add_role(); and add_cap(); Thanks @Hobo for the link that helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help.  If all you want is a pretty UI for `add_role()` and `app_cap()` [Justin Tadlock's Members plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) might save you the time of writing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [advanced access manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) plugin for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit a user to only edit their own posts using this bit of code.

```
function my_authored_content($query) {

//get current user info to see if they are allowed to access ANY posts and pages
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// set current user to $is_user
$is_user = $current_user->user_login;

//if is admin or 'is_user' does not equal #username
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){
    //if in the admin panel
    if($query->is_admin) {

        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);

    }
    return $query;
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_authored_content');

function remove_menu_items() {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    //hides comments menu
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
    // hides posts menu
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
    hides pages menu
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
}
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items' );
```

Hope this helps you :-)